# BERT from tfhub SLOW and not using GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying out [this BERT model from TFHub](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1).
Sadly it's running extremely slow, and only using 1-2% GPU according to Windows Task Manager.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

tf.test.is_gpu_available(True) # returns True

max_seq_length = 128

input_word_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_word_ids")
input_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_mask")
segment_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name="segment_ids")

bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1", trainable=False)
pooled_out, seq_out = bert_layer([input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids])
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids], outputs=[pooled_out, seq_out])

t = tf.random.uniform((1000, max_seq_length), maxval=1, dtype=tf.int32)
outputs = model.predict([t, t, t]) # super slow...
```

Comment: It might be possible that the program is executing on CPU instead of GPU. Please verify on that. Also, verify if you have installed `tensorflow-gpu`

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. As already mentioned by Ashwin Geet D'SA, make sure you have `tensorflow-gpu` installed (not `tensorflow`). Run this test to verify that the GPU is accessible:

```
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
```

Comment: I have tensorflow-gpu installed. Your test code prints 
"Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0"  

When you ran my code snippet, was it fast and did it use your GPU?

Comment: My code was orders of magnitude faster and used the GPU once I switched to it. I didn't run your code but mine is similar to yours. One difference is that I'm using real inputs instead of dummy random ones, could it be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.

- I verified that I installed tensorflow-gpu 1.14. But still, I was getting the same level of performance in the machine with GPU and without GPU.
- After running "tf.test.gpu_device_name()" I got "Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0"
- [From the GitHub issue page](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/75#issuecomment-457506307), one person suggested using the following code

  os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"

After adding this, the THUB code was using GPUs and I instantly got more than 5 times performance improvement.